# curl POST cmd works to post to execution evidence in xray but doesn't work with python requests.post

Tags: curl, python-requests, jira-xray

Below curl command works if post to execution evidence in Xray and attaching test.log file to evidence field:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -u user:pwd --data @test.json https://jira.opentv.com/rest/raven/1.0/api/testrun/{id}/attachment
```

where test.json has this,

```
{
"data":"VGhpcyBmaWxlIGlzIHRlc3RpbmcgZm9yIHVwbG9hZCB0byBleGVjdXRpb24gZGV0YWlscy4=",
"filename":"test.log",
"contentType":"application/json"
}
```

(in json 'data' is base64 encoded which is only supported in xray)

but when i try the same with below requests.post it fails.

```
requests.post('https://jira.opentv.com/rest/raven/1.0/api/testrun/{id}/attachment',headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json'},data={"data":"VGhpcyBmaWxlIGlzIHRlc3RpbmcgZm9yIHVwbG9hZCB0byBleGVjdXRpb24gZGV0YWlscy4=","fileName":"test.log","Content-Type":"application/json"},auth=('user', 'pwd'))
```

Thanks in Advance..

the curl cmd is executed from linux machine and python requests.post from windows. Both are reachable to Xray.

Comment: https://curl.trillworks.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a named "json" parameter instead of "data". You also had a typo in the contentType of the paypload.

The correct code would be something like:

```
import requests    
requests.post('https://sandbox.xpand-it.com/rest/raven/1.0/api/testrun/4448/attachment',headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json'}, json={"data":"VGhpcyBmaWxlIGlzIHRlc3RpbmcgZm9yIHVwbG9hZCB0byBleGVjdXRpb24gZGV0YWlscy4=", "filename":"test.log", "contentType":"application/json"},auth=('user', 'pass'))
```